# Чи існує слово глупість?

Tags: існування-слова

Пошукав в наявних онлайн словниках, і *глупість* там не знайшов. Є тільки *глупий*, *глупо*, *глупота*. Проте знайшов у творі «Крутіж» Б. Лепкого:

> Хтось якусь **глупість** ляпне, підхоплять — і пішло. Наймудрішого чоловіка осмішать і забудуть, що, насміхаючись над своїми чільними людьми, самі з себе сміються.

Як на мене, то слово *дурість* має інший відтінок, і ним не можна замінити слово *глупість*. Та й це дивно виглядає:

- дурний — дурість,
- глупий — дурість?

Comment: В українській мові не існує такого слова. Але є тупість і дурість.

Comment: А чим між собою відрізняються російські слова *глупьій* и *дурной*?

Comment: @Yola *Глупый* використовують як постійну якість та як характеристику розуму, а *дурной* — часто як тимчасову та як характеристику поведінки, вчинків. Перше слово значно м’якіше, а друге — іноді як лайка. *Дурной* має й багато інших значень (зокрема, *що робить різкі та необдумані вчинки*).

Answer (score 6):

Ольга Кобилянська використовує слово *глупість* у романі «[Апостол черні](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Kh1KDwAAQBAJ&pg=PP46)»:

> «**Глупість**, Юлій?» — повторила Оксана уражено. — «**Глупість**, Оксано, марнота, а коли хочеш, то чистий припадок, що кождому мужикові може в дорозі трапитися».

Слово *глупість* зустрічається в літературно-мистецькому публіцистичному журналі українців Словаччини «[Дукля](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vnNgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22&dq=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22)», щоправда разом з нецензурною лексикою:

> А Орко — не дурний же хлопець! — атакував навально, ще й повній мірі використовуючи той пащекуватий чортів антураж, — і ні секунди передиху! — тільки-но посуну фігуру, як він тут же: «Ага! Добре! Ти, голубчику, зробив велику дурницю!» — з пащек тим часом: «Га-га! Го-го! Дайʼму, дайʼму!» — тільки-но задумаюсь на хвильку, як він тут же: «А казали, що ти вмієш грати… я ось давно походив!» — з єхидством, а з пащек тим часом: «Ходи, кур-р-р… Орко все одно тебе розібʼє в пух і прах… не грай варʼята!» — пішов, пересунув фігуру, як сновида… а той знову: «Ось і спіймав я тебе — капець тобі!» — і руками, руками… над дошкою, ніби два орли стервʼятники, та хап мою вежу чи офіцера. «А це ще більша **глупість** твоя!» «А зараз і твоїй королеві скручу голову!» «Ще хід — і піднімай руки!» «Ха-ха! — га-га!» «Здавайся, блядь!» «Орку, тисни, скурвого сина, тисни!»

Іван Багряний використовує це слово в «[На новий шлях](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=RSUaAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22&dq=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22)»:

> Чи треба підкреслювати наївність і печальну **глупість** таких тверджень?

Дмитро Кешеля вживає *глупість* у «[Пора грибної печалі](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=3eowAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22&dq=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22)»:

> А, Петрику, чим ти журишся, — спокійно відповів Великий речник. — На старість людина так само дуріє, як і за молодості. Біда лише в тому, що у старого **глупість** набагато ширша і довша…

За допомогою [Google Книги](//books.google.com) можна знайти ще більше прикладів.

У Etymological Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language Ярослава Рудницького, том І, на ст. 653 воно є серед похідних до слова *глупий*, з посиланням на [Українсько-німецький словник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) Желехівського:

> Deriv. *глу́по, глупота́, **глу́пість**, глу́пощі, глу́пство, оглупі́ти, доглу́патися,* dial. *о́глуп*, Wd. *туп[т]а́к, глупе́й, глупта́вий, глупува́тий* (Желеховський 1, 144-145);

Також, з посиланням на [Лексис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) Лаврентія Зизанія:

> … глупость (1596 Зизаній), глу́пост (1627), глу́пство (1596 Зизаній, 1627 Беринда), …

Вважаю, що наведені приклади доводять, що слово існує.

Comment: Та навіть якби не було таких прикладів. В укранській суфікс "-ість" творить іменники, будь то "ніжність", "дурість" чи "ницість". Що заважає створити слово "глупість"?

Answer (score 1):

Я можу сказати наступне про *глупість*. Граматично форма утворена правильно. Також треба памʼятати, що крім такої форми існують ще й: *глупство* (яке буде точним синонімом), *глупота* (але краще до таке слово вживати стосовно до вчинків). Також є синоніми *дурість*, *тупість*.

> [глупство](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) поведінка, вчинки і т. ін., що суперечать здоровому глузду

> [ГЛУПСТВО](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghlupstvo), а, *сер., рідко.*
>
> 1. Властивість за значенням глупий. — *Ви велика людина і добре розпізнасте глупства і доброчинність у суспільстві* (Натан Рибак, Помилка.., 1956, 274).
> 2. Нерозумний вчинок, задум, вислів. [Ярош:] *Ні, поки ти молодий, ти не забезпечений від глупства* (Іван Микитенко, I, 1957, 510); — *Не кажи, вуйку, глупства, — зашипіла озираючись Вінцусиха* (Ігор Муратов, Буковинська повість, 1959, 152).

> [ГЛУПОТА](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghlupota), и, *жін., рідко.* Відсутність розуму, розсудливості, поміркованості; дурість. *Немає друга понад мудрість, Ні ворога над глупоту, Так, як нема любові в світі Над матірню любов святу* (Іван Франко, XI, 1952, 66); *Я лишився з своїми думками, з своїм нерозгаданим питанням: як це так, що порожнеча зживається з повнотою, глупота з розумом?* (Дмитро Ткач, Жди.., 1959, 66).

Але не треба тут змішувати російські слова *дурной* та українське *дурний*.
Якщо в російській основне значення слова — це щось погане, не приємне (наприклад *дурной тон, дурной запах*), то в український то буде *нерозумний*, *глупий*.

Comment: Взяв на себе сміливість додати тлумачення слів зі словників і виходить, що щодо вчинків краще вживати саме *глупство*, а не *глупоту*.

Comment: Це суб'єктивізм чистої води(жодного обгрунтування) -> Але не треба тут змішувати російські слова дурной та українське дурний. Якщо в російській основне значення слова — це щось погане, не приємне (наприклад дурной тон, дурной запах), то в український то буде нерозумний, глупий.

Answer (score 1):

**СУМ-20**, який вважається найбільш актуальним тлумачним словником на 2021 рік НЕ містить даного слова.

Натомість, він [містить](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18804&page=643) слово *ГЛУ́ПСТВО*.

> ГЛУ́ПСТВО , а, с., рідко. 1 . Властивість за знач. глу́пий 1 . – Ви
> велика людина і добре розпізнаєте глупства і доброчинність у
> суспільстві (Н. Рибак); – Значить, на вашу думку, юначе, якась там
> золота чи усипана брильянтами дорогоцінність була б для науки
> важливіша від цього єдиного в своєму роді письмового документа?
> Дурниці, глупство! (В. Владко). 2 . Нерозумний вчинок, задум, вислів
> . [ Ярош :] Ні, поки ти молодий, ти не забезпечений від глупства (І.
> Микитенко); – Не кажи, вуйку, глупства, – зашипіла озираючись
> Вінцусиха (І. Муратов); Ще вчора ввечері він подумав, яке глупство
> мало був не вчинив, просячи руки Доброчинової дочки за свого сина (І.
> Білик).

Звідси, можна зробити припущення, що слово *глупість* відсутнє в офіційній українській та одним із його синонімів в українській є слово *ГЛУПСТВО*.

Comment: Правда, СУМ-20 [згадав](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=67767&page=2138) в прикладах: *Дурні, дурні! Хтось якусь глупість* [дурницю] *ляпне, підхоплять – і пішло. Наймудрішого чоловіка осмішать і забудуть, що, насміхаючись над своїми чільними людьми, самі з себе сміються* (Б. Лепкий).

Comment: Цікаво. Я не буду питати як ви знайшли це :) І цього немає в СУМ-11. Можливо, ідея була - продемонструвати використання того слова, але при цьому "глупість" вважається все одно неправильним словом. Хоча навіщо тоді було взагалі включати такий приклад?Коротше, енігма. Я був би схильний відкинути це як помилку укладача словника.